# How can access $auth.getToken('local') in a service?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am new in nuxtjs.i am trying to create a service like EventService.js.From EventService.js i want to get data using axios. but i want to set Authorization header.But can't get the access token from $auth.getToken('local'). i don't want to set Authorization header every axios request.Thanks

```
import axios from 'axios'

 const apiClient = axios.create({
   baseURL: `example.com`,
   headers: {
   Accept: 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   'Authorization': "Bearer " +  **$auth.getToken('local')**
 }
})

export default {
   getEvents() {
     return apiClient.get('/events')
}

}
```

Comment: Read about axios' request and response interceptors.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter  for now axios' request and response interceptors solve my issue.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

axios interceptors solved my problem

```
apiClient.interceptors.request.use(
        (config) => {config.headers["Authorization"] =cookies.get("auth._token.local")
        .replace(/%/g, " ") 
   return config
   }, 
function(error) {
  return Promise.reject(error) })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import 'axios' in your main.js (entry file) and add the following:

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localstorage.getItem('token')}`;
```

And when you setup your token for the first time, your can set it up on the localstorage and assign again to the axios defaults headers:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const token = <AUTH_TOKEN>
// when setting the token
localstorage.setItem('token', token)
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
```

This will be enough to send the Authorization header in every axios request you make.

Comment: i have to call many different endpoint means need multiple axios instance. for now interceptors slove my problem.